# Joining two internal lists within a python object

Tags: python, list, google-api

Quite new to python, so apologies if this question has been asked elsewhere.

I'm trying to create an object (HEADER) that contains whatever the user enters into the METRICS object excluding the 3 initial characters, namely 'ga:'.

The output I'm aiming for would be:

```
METRICS = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']
HEADER = ['sessions', 'users']
```

What I've done so far almost achieves this, however it stores the output as multiple lists within a single object, which then means (I believe) that it writes and re-writes over each list and ultimately outputs only the last list, which in this case, would simply be ['users'].

```
METRICS = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']

for idx, val in enumerate(METRICS):
    HEADER = val[3:].split()
    print(HEADER)

print(HEADER)
```

You can see what's happening, as the print function within the for loop shows both headers, but the print function outside the for loop only shows the final header.

The approach I'm trying to take, and hence the title of the question, is to find a way to join all the internal lists within the object into one list, which would hopefully solve the problem.

I also have a feeling I might be way overcomplicating things, and there's a much easier way to go about what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
METRICS = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']
HEADER = []

for val in METRICS:
    HEADER.append(val[3:])

print(HEADER)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here you can simply approach the solution. Like, you can use split with ':' separator instead of item[:3], that can handle your desire output dynamically.

```
METRICS = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']
HEADER = list()
for item in METRICS:
   output = item.split(':')[1]
   HEADER.append(output)
   print(output)
print(HEADER)
```

> Output look like,

```
sessions
users
['sessions', 'users']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
METRICS = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']
HEADERS = [item[3:] for item in METRICS]
```

Answer (score 0):

> which then means (I believe) that it writes and re-writes over each
> list and ultimately outputs only the last list, which in this case,
> would simply be ['users'].

You are partially right here. **"HEADER" is not a list but only a string object(variable)** and **because of the loop, the value in it is re-written**

Its fairly simple.
I'll use your code and **suggest the modifications** that are needed with comments.

**Code:**

```
METRICS = ['ga:sessions', 'ga:users']

# Create an empty list named "HEADERS" which will store all of the "HEADER" variables
HEADERS = []

for idx, val in enumerate(METRICS):
    HEADER = val[3:].split()

    # Since you were able to get the value of "HEADER", all we have to do is append/store it inside of "HEADERS" list
    HEADERS.append(HEADER)
    print(HEADER)

print(HEADERS)
```

**Output:**

```
['sessions']
['users']
[['sessions'], ['users']]
```